# How to deploy a delegate control in the same feature as custom actions?

Tags: feature

I'm trying to deploy a delegate control in the same feature as some custom actions. All the actions are deployed and work correctly. However, the control is not being deployed. If I create a new project with only the delegate control, this works and is deployed right. Is there something I'm missing when mixing controls and custom actions in the same feature?

Comment: can you provide your element.xml file contents..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I found that the error was that the manifest file --that ussually is generated automatically by Visual Studio-- was edited manualy by the person who created the project. So, the new files I added into the solution were excluded from it. I changed back the configuration to maintain the file automatically again and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Should work just fine, here is an example from one of our products.

Feature.xml

```
<Feature Id="BD315B60-A1CD-4e64-8537-E4EE3FBFFAB3"
         Title="$Resources:MuhimbiAuditProvisioningResources,Feature_Title_Farm;"
         Description="$Resources:MuhimbiAuditProvisioningResources,Feature_Description_Farm;"
         ImageUrl="Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/muhimbi_feature.gif"
         Version="1.0.2.2"
         Scope="Farm"
         Hidden="FALSE"
         ReceiverAssembly="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit, Version=1.0.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c9db4759c9eaad12"
         ReceiverClass="Muhimbi.SharePoint.Audit.FarmAuditing.FeatureReceiver"
         RequireResources = "FALSE"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

    <ElementManifests>
      <ElementManifest Location="TemplateAssocations\GlobalSiteTemplateStaple.xml" />
      <ElementManifest Location="CustomActions\ElementsShared.xml" />
      <ElementManifest Location="CustomActions\Elements.xml" />
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

ElementsShared.xml

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">    
  <!-- Delegate control that is included on every page for tracking audits -->
  <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead"
           Sequence="50"
           ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/Muhimbi.SharePointAudit/AuditTracker.ascx"
            />
</Elements>
```

Comment: @Muhimbi. I think I'm doing just the same. However, I did not create the project with the custom actions. I'm trying to add my control to that existing project. Is there some configuration about paths or whatever than can be affecting this?? For some reason it just doesn't deploy

Comment: @Muhimbi. Also, are you guys deploying something else in the same feature. If I do the deployment with only the control, it works. When adding something else is when it breaks.

Comment: As you can see from the feature definition, we are deploying custom actions in 3 element files.